# How to plot a java object in a lineChart with MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

my question is: how can I plot in a LineChart (library MPAndroidChart) a java object from this class:

**Object Class**

```
public class Glycaemia {
private String date_of_addition, notes_by_the_user;
private float glycaemia;

public Glycaemia(){}

public Glycaemia(float value, String n)
{
    this.glycaemia = value;
    this.notes_by_the_user = n;
    this.date_of_addition = setDate();
}

public Glycaemia(float value, String s, String s1)
{
    this.glycaemia = value;
    this.notes_by_the_user = s;
    this.date_of_addition = s1;

}

private String setDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String date = sdf.format(new Date());
    return date;
}

public String getDate_of_addition()
{
    return date_of_addition;
}

public String getNotes_by_the_user()
{
    return notes_by_the_user;
}

public float getGlycaemia()
{
    return glycaemia;
}
}
```

I want to set object'addition_date on the X-axis and it glycaemia_value on the Y-axis. Is there any way to plot a java object using this library? Something like creating a "format" which adapt the value to the chart?

Answer (score 1):

Set the glycaimia values cassually, then change the xAxisValues. Here is a sample code on how to change the xvalues

```
final String[] months = new String[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr" };

IAxisValueFormatter formatter = new IAxisValueFormatter() {

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return months [(int) value];
    }

    @Override
    public int getDecimalDigits() {  return 0; }
};

XAxis xAxis = mLineChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah but the "months array" in my case needs to have data_addition value from the glycaemia_value. And where do i have to pass the glycaemia_value in the formatter??